# Smart contract that can receive and send NFTs

Tags: solidity, nft, openzeppelin, polygon

I'm trying to make a smart contract that can receive and send NFTs. I have something like this. I know this is wrong but what do I change? Also I'm trying to do this on the Polygon Network, not sure if that affects anything. Thanks

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Contract is ERC721 {
  
  uint num_of_nfts = 0;
  mapping (uint => ERC721) nft_holdings;

  function call_when_recieve_nft(nft) public {
    nft_holdings[num_of_nfts] = nft;
  }
}
```

Comment: ERC721 is a nft collection contract, not an individual nft. One ERC721 contract can issue almost unlimited nfts if it would like to. Also, I don't think you need to make your contract a ERC721, unless you want to issue your own nfts to people.

Answer (score 1):

A smart contract cannot block receiving NFTs. So the receiving part is already done when a smart contract is created. Sending NFTs can be done by calling the `transferFrom` function of the NFT smart contract.

Example:

```
interface IERC721 {
     function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) external;
}

contract TransferNFT {
    function transferNFT(address NFTAddress, address _receiver, uint256 _NFTId) external {
        IERC721 NFT = IERC721(NFTAddress); // Create an instance of the NFT contract

        // Calling the NFT smart contract transferFrom function
        // From - receiver - NFT id
        NFT.transferFrom(address(this), _receiver, _NFTId);
    }
}
```

**=-]**